# Display wordpress post using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am developing a plugin, where a selectable tree is displayed in a page. After a tree selection is made, some queries are submitted and the posts that are the results of these queries should appear in the same page. The whole querying is implemented with jQuery and as a result I have the `postId`s.

Thus, I want to display the content in a `<div>` element a post. The content of the `<div>` should contain all the information as in the `single.php` of my theme.

The information that I have in javascript is the `postId` and Post title.

Is it feasible?

Comment: are you using pure javascript or jQuery

Comment: What is the main reason for this function? If it is a single post you could load it on page load and show the div with jquery. If it is an list of posts and you want to open them in a sort of a lightbox you need an ajax function.

Comment: I want to implement this functionality in my plugin. I have a selectable tree in a page and according to the selections, the appropriate posts should appear in the same page.

Comment: Then take a look at this page, i have used this before with succes. But that was building a theme not an plugin. http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/how-to-ajaxify-wordpress-theme.html

Comment: it looks like you need to use PHP for this. Cause you are making a selection of (queries/tags/categories even depending on the tree): http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

I wouldn't know how to do this in JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into jQUery's load method. http://api.jquery.com/load/
Its basically an ajax call, whose response becomes html of a div's (or any container) on your page.

These are the steps that comes to mind:

1. Someone will click on "node" in your tree (I hope this gives you
   postID)
2. Create the URL which will hit your php file and send postID along
   with it. e.g.:

> yoursite.com/single.php?postid=selected post id

1. Use jQuery load method:

> `$('#show_post_here').load('yoursite.com/single.php?postid=selected_post_id')`

1. If you single.php only return the html of a single post then you are
   good to go else follow next step to filter out the html from your
   response.
2. The .load() method, allows us to specify a portion of the remote
   document to be inserted.

> ```
> $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
> ```

This statement will take out the html of container from your response and insert it into #result